# query without limit works faster than query with limit

Tags: postgresql

What is the explanation why the same query with limit 100 works slower than similar query without limit 100.  The two queries run against the same database and and the result-set is less than 100

The original query was generated by hibernate and had some extra joins.  Based on the feedback I got I made the query simpler and ran

```
VACUUM  FULL ANALYZE events
VACUUM  FULL ANALYZE resources
```

But the problem still exist.

Thanks!

```
explain ANALYZE
SELECT e.id
FROM events e,
     resources r
WHERE e.resource_id = r.id
  AND (resource_type_id = '19872817' OR resource_type_id = '282')
ORDER BY occurrence_date DESC LIMIT 100
```

outputs...

```
"Limit  (cost=0.98..86362.46 rows=100 width=12) (actual time=61958.090..185854.425 rows=22 loops=1)"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.98..16791263.94 rows=19443 width=12) (actual time=61958.087..185854.392 rows=22 loops=1)"
"        ->  Index Scan using eventoccurrencedateindex on events e  (cost=0.56..2295556.29 rows=31819630 width=16) (actual time=0.028..31770.948 rows=31819491 loops=1)"
"        ->  Index Scan using resources_pkey on resources r  (cost=0.42..0.45 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=31819491)"
"              Index Cond: (id = e.resource_id)"
"              Filter: ((resource_type_id = 19872817) OR (resource_type_id = 282))"
"              Rows Removed by Filter: 1"
"Total runtime: 185854.569 ms"
```

and

```
explain ANALYZE
SELECT e.id
FROM events e,
     resources r
WHERE e.resource_id = r.id
  AND (resource_type_id = '19872817' OR resource_type_id = '282')
ORDER BY occurrence_date DESC
```

outputs...

```
"Sort  (cost=455353.69..455402.30 rows=19443 width=12) (actual time=1.942..1.947 rows=22 loops=1)"
"  Sort Key: e.occurrence_date"
"  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 26kB"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=42.30..453968.67 rows=19443 width=12) (actual time=0.720..1.900 rows=22 loops=1)"
"        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on resources r  (cost=9.53..309.53 rows=86 width=4) (actual time=0.120..0.306 rows=34 loops=1)"
"              Recheck Cond: ((resource_type_id = 19872817) OR (resource_type_id = 282))"
"              ->  BitmapOr  (cost=9.53..9.53 rows=86 width=0) (actual time=0.109..0.109 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on resources_type_fk_index  (cost=0.00..4.74 rows=43 width=0) (actual time=0.016..0.016 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                          Index Cond: (resource_type_id = 19872817)"
"                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on resources_type_fk_index  (cost=0.00..4.74 rows=43 width=0) (actual time=0.092..0.092 rows=34 loops=1)"
"                          Index Cond: (resource_type_id = 282)"
"        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on events e  (cost=32.78..5259.29 rows=1582 width=16) (actual time=0.041..0.043 rows=1 loops=34)"
"              Recheck Cond: (resource_id = r.id)"
"              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on events_resource_fk_index  (cost=0.00..32.38 rows=1582 width=0) (actual time=0.037..0.037 rows=1 loops=34)"
"                    Index Cond: (resource_id = r.id)"
"Total runtime: 2.054 ms"
```

Comment: If the observed number of rows differs from the expected -->> your statistics are absent or off.

Comment: why LEFT JOIN when you need an INNER JOIN? And why using two tables that aren't used anywhere? And yes, LIMIT has some issues but in your case you should fix your query first.

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL are you running? And does it look like this bug report: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/541A2335.3060100@agliodbs.com

Comment: "PostgreSQL 9.3.3 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4), 64-bit"

Comment: It is very possible that my problem is what is described in the bug report.  Is there a workaround to this bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increasing the limit size to 1000 caused Postgres to use a different plan which worked much faster.